# Sticky position + Flex alignment anchors at top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When using position sticky and a align-self: start; to avoid flex stretching--the content grows upwards instead of pushing down. Is there a workaround or a different way of implementing this where the content pushes down instead of up.

To test.

1. Scroll down to when the sticky position **stops** being sticky.
2. Click on the 2nd purple box
3. You will see that the content grows upwards instead
   of pushing the page down.

   How can I push the page down instead?

If you remove   *align-self:flex-start;* then it works as intended and pushes down but the orange background is too long. It should only match the content.

Codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/homedepot/pen/ZEGmNyR)

```js
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle')

toggle.forEach((t) => {
  t.addEventListener('click', () => {
    t.style.height = '500px'
  })
})
```

```css
html {
  color: white;
}

section {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  align-self:flex-start;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle {
  background: purple;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
}

.more {
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="more">
  spacer
</div>

<section>
  
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sticky">
    <p> sticky </p>
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>Top A</p>
      <p>row A2</p>
      <p>row A3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>Top B</p>
      <p>row B2</p>
      <p>row B3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>

<div class="more">
  spacer
</div>
```

Comment: If i keep the console on the right hand side, sticky behaviour does not work on codepen.
I am using 23' monitor

Comment: If you run the code snippet here it works, just scroll down to the 2nd purple box and click and you will see it flow upwards @UtsavPatel